# How to Post a null byte from an edit or update page on ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to update a page with user information and pictures, it works when I upload a new image to update the old image.

But when I update the page without uploading an image, it gives a null reference exception error.

What I want to achieve is if I don't want to change the image, it should still retain the old image.

This is the action for the update/edit view

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(CombinedMember model)
    {
        try
        {
            //Updated Images

            byte[] Signature = new byte[model.MSignature.InputStream.Length];
            byte[] Photo = new byte[model.MPhoto.InputStream.Length];
            byte[] Signature2 = new byte[model.WSignature.InputStream.Length];

            model.MSignature.InputStream.Read(Signature, 0, Signature.Length);
            model.MPhoto.InputStream.Read(Photo, 0, Photo.Length);
            model.WSignature.InputStream.Read(Signature2, 0, Signature2.Length);

            WebService.UpdateMember(int.Parse(Session["memberidedit"].ToString()), model.newmember.SURNAME, model.newmember.OTHER_NAMES, model.newmember.DESIGNATION, model.newmember.ORGANISATION, model.newmember.DEPARTMENT, model.newmember.ADDRESS, model.newmember.PHONE, model.newmember.EMAIL, model.newmember.STAFFID, model.newmember.MEMBERSHIPNO, DateTime.Parse(model.newmember.DATE.ToString()), int.Parse(Session["userid"].ToString()), int.Parse(model.newmember.FLAG.ToString()),Signature,Photo);

             WebService.UpdateWitness(int.Parse(Session["witnessid"].ToString()), int.Parse(Session["memberidedit"].ToString()), model.newwitness.W_SURNAME, model.newwitness.W_OTHER_NAMES, model.newwitness.STATUS,Session["membershipno"].ToString(), Signature2);



                Session["member"] = "Details Updated successfully";
            }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.LogError(ex.ToString());
        }

        return RedirectToAction("MembersDetails");
    }
```

this is the view section for the upload

```
<div class="form-group">
                            <label for="input-username">UPLOAD MEMBER SIGNATURE</label>
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(mw => mw.MSignature, new { type = "file" })
                            </div>
                    <div class="right" align="right">
                        @Html.Raw(TempData["mSign"])
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="input-username">UPLOAD PHOTO</label>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(mw => mw.MPhoto, new { type = "file" })

                        <div class="right" align="right">
                            @Html.Raw(TempData["mPhoto"])
                        </div>
                    </div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="input-username">
UPLOAD WITNESS SIGNATURE</label>@Html.TextBoxFor(mw => mw.WSignature, new { type = "file" })
                        <div class="right" align="right">
                            @Html.Raw(TempData["wSign"])
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you heard of null checking:

```
byte[] Signature;  
byte[] Photo;  
byte[] Signature2;  

if (Model.MSignature != null)
{
    Signature = new byte[model.MSignature.InputStream.Length];
    model.MSignature.InputStream.Read(Signature, 0, Signature.Length);
}

if (Model.MPhoto != null)
{
    new byte[model.MPhoto.InputStream.Length];
    model.MPhoto.InputStream.Read(Photo, 0, Photo.Length);
}

if (Model.WSignature != null) 
{
    new byte[model.WSignature.InputStream.Length];
    model.WSignature.InputStream.Read(Signature2, 0, Signature2.Length);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you create another method

```
WebService.UpdateMember(int.Parse(Session["memberidedit"].ToString()),
model.newmember.SURNAME, model.newmember.OTHER_NAMES,
model.newmember.DESIGNATION, model.newmember.ORGANISATION,  
model.newmember.DEPARTMENT, 
model.newmember.ADDRESS, model.newmember.PHONE, model.newmember.EMAIL,
model.newmember.STAFFID, model.newmember.MEMBERSHIPNO, 
DateTime.Parse(model.newmember.DATE.ToString()), 
int.Parse(Session["userid"].ToString()), 
int.Parse(model.newmember.FLAG.ToString()),Signature);
```

and call it when there is no Photo provided

Comment: there are 3 images (photo, signature1, signature2)

Comment: Why don't you check in your WebMethod for null values on the images and act accordianlly?